# What is new with quark-Gluon Plasma and the bubble formed at RHIC?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

RHIC experiment results of forming Quark-Gluon Plasma and a possible bubble was news few months ago.  I cannot find any follow up news after that.  Does anybody know anything new in this front?  I am especially interested to hear about the bubble formed.

Edit: The following are some links about this story.

http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/02/100215101018.htm

http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2010-02/rhic-collider-creates-72-trillion-degrees-fahrenheit-quark-gluon-plasma

Did a bubble actually formed?  What have they found about the bubble?  I want more scientific details than one would expect from a newspaper article.

Comment: Hi Sony, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This is a good question, I'm actually having trouble finding information on it myself. Could you perhaps link to some reference for the "bubble" discovery to give us a starting point? (Also, it would be better if you can be more specific about what you're looking for, not just "does anybody know anything new?".)

Comment: Why don't you read up a bit on the new heavy ion results from CMS? http://cms.web.cern.ch/news/new-cms-results-heavy-ion-collisions

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: I edited the question according to your request.

Comment: @annav:  Thanks for the URL for a site.  However, that site does not provide an answer to my question.